# how to see how many commit ahead or behind my local master is compare to my remote master in git

Tags: git, gitlab

Pretty new to git and we are using gitlab .
My question is probably very simple ,I just want to know how many commit ahead or behind my local master is compare to my remote master in git. So that when I do git pull I know exactly how many commits I am pulling in.

Comment: Run `git fetch` to update your remote-tracking names, then run `git branch -v` or `git branch -vv` (compares each of your branches to its upstream) or `git status` (tells you just about the branch you have checked out right now). There are more-specific methods for gathering these counts for scripting purposes, but that doesn't seem like what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `git log` to see the difference in commits between the two branches. In your case you can do:

```
git fetch origin master // this will fetch the remote master
git log master..origin/master // this will give commits not in master but in origin/master
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to see how many commits then all you have to do is run a `git status` command after changing into that local directory for your project on your terminal window.

```
cd into desired directory
git status
```

If your local branch is up to date with the remote branch this  is what it would look like
[image]

But if your local branch is not up to date with the remote branch then it will look like this.
[image]

**NOTE:** Notice from the image it says to run `git push` this is because your local repository is ahead of your remote Gitlab environment. But if it was the reverse where the remote GitLab repo is ahead of your local repo then this would be `git pull`.